# How to autoescape form value in UpdateView in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I have a form where I use TinyMCE on textareas because I need my users have the option to style the text they enter. It works fine and saves the html codes to the model. I use the safe mode to show the values in the way the users entered it and it works fine but I have an UpdateView where the user can edit what was entered.

My problem is that if the user uses the UpdateView to change whet he entered he see the html code in the UpdateView like below and I have no idea how to solve this.

`<h2>Text</h2>`

`<b><p>More text</p></b>`

Can I autoescape off the form? I tried these methods but not worked:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Edit report</h2>
    <h5 class="my-3">You can edit your report here:</h5>
    {% autoescape off %}
        {{ form.as_p|safe }} <!-- tried it separately -->
    {% end autoescape %}

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning my-3">Submit changes</button>
```

Comment: Are you using tinymce in the updateview as well?

Comment: Oh my God what a silly mistake :D Thank you!